# How would you store metadata about a file for use with command line application

Tags: command-line-interface

I am working on a command line application that interacts with a service to pull down "script" files via a rest api. When interacting with the api, I need to refer to the scripts by their ID (returned by the api). I would like to save these "scripts" to a file locally (for editing and source control). My problem is that I don't want to save the "scripts" to a file where the name of the file is the id of the script. I would like to name the "script" file, the same as the script name. The other thing, is that the "scripts" can have the same name but different id's and they would need to be written to different files locally. How would you go about managing which file corresponds to which id?

For Example:

Script #1:

- Name: Sample Script
- ID: 3

Script #2:

- Name: Sample Script
- ID: 4

I pull in Script #1 to a file locally:
FETCH: Script #1 -> Save to File -> Sample Script

I then want to pull in Script #2 to a file locally
FETCH: Script #2 -> Save to File -> Sample Script
**In this case the Script #1 would get overwritten by Script #2**

Comment: I probably don't understand the question, but have you thought about saving those files in different folders?

Comment: @StephanBranczyk yes, however I would like to account for if the user does not want to put them in different folders.

Comment: Why not use both the script name and ID?  For example "Sample_Script_3" or "Sample_Script_4"

Comment: I was thinking about doing this, however I was wondering if there was any other ideas out there...